# How best to save and share GraphQL Playground queries and query variables?

Tags: graphql

I would like to save the GraphQL queries and query variables with the GraphQL playground.  I would like to avoid losing the queries when clearing browser cache and avoid copy and pasting to share.

I have tried copy and pasting both the queries and query variables to a cloud file as a back up, which is at minimum two steps.

Is there a way to save these as query files so they can be backed up in source control?

Or to add a plugin that saves the queries for sharing with team members?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Chrome Browser Extension called Altair GraphQL Client. It will give you a Save option. You can save queries and query variables in collections.

[image]

We can export the collections to a file. The exported file will be a json file with agc extension. This file can be backed up in source control.